# Iterate over sublists to create dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to iterate over sublists within a list to create a dictionary where elements of the sublists are keys ad values are all 0.

Example:

```
keys = [['desk','lamp','printer'],['mouse','chair','desk','pencil']]
```

I want the output:

```
output = [{'desk':0,'lamp':0,'printer':0},{'mouse':0,'chair':0,'desk':0,'pencil':0}]
```

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
d = {}
output= []

for i in range(len(keys)):
    for w in keys[i]:
        output.append(d[w] = 0)
```

but when I run this I get a message keywords can't be an expression.

Since I have different elements within the sublists of keys, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use list comprehension and [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) with `0` as  value:

```
>>> keys = [['desk','lamp','printer'],['mouse','chair','desk','pencil']]
>>> [dict.fromkeys(l, 0) for l in keys]
[{'desk': 0, 'lamp': 0, 'printer': 0}, {'mouse': 0, 'desk': 0, 'pencil': 0, 'chair': 0}]
```

First parameter given to `fromkeys` is an iterable of keys and second parameter is a value to set for each key.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple approach:

```
[{y:0 for y in x} for x in keys]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest a dict comprehension inside of a list comprehension:

```
>>> keys = [['desk','lamp','printer'],['mouse','chair','desk','pencil']]
>>> [{k:0 for k in ks} for ks in keys]
[{'printer': 0, 'desk': 0, 'lamp': 0}, {'desk': 0, 'pencil': 0, 'mouse': 0, 'chair': 0}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
keys = [['desk','lamp','printer'],['mouse','chair','desk','pencil']]
output= []

for i in range(len(keys)):
    d = {}
    for w in keys[i]:
        d[w] = 0
    output.append(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
abc = [['desk','lamp','printer'],['mouse','chair','desk','pencil']]

new_array = []
for array in abc:
    dic = {}
    for value in array:
        dic[value] = 0
    new_array.append(dic)

print(new_array)
```

`keys` is special in python, avoid to use it :D

Comment: `keys` is not a reserved word, nor the name of a built-in function.